# ¿Cómo navegar entre pestañas del componente Tabs de Vuesax desde cualquier acción en vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

Mi proyecto está creado en vue.
Como componente de css uso vuesax.
He implementado un componente que este trae llamado tabs.
El componente funciona perfectamente, el problema es a la hora de navegar desde cualquier acción que yo cree. Por ejemplo.
Este no trae el fragment url para abrir la tab requerida, el método con el cuál se abren las tabs, es mediante push. Intenté hacer algo parecido a lo que tenían en sus componentes pero no funcionó.
Lo que deseo hacer, es que a la hora de yo crear un botón en cualquier componente, este me llame alguna tab que deseo abrir.

```
<vs-tabs @clicked="tabClicked" @changed="tabChanged">
              <vs-tab id="inicio" vs-label="INICIO">
                <div>
                  <br>
                  <UserPanel></UserPanel>
                </div>
              </vs-tab>
              <vs-tab  vs-label="INVERSIONES">
                <div id="compra">
                  <vs-tabs   vs-alignment="fixed">
                    <vs-tab class="vs-tabs--content" vs-label="Comprar paquete">
                      <div>
                        <BuyPack></BuyPack>
                      </div>
                    </vs-tab>
                    <vs-tab class="vs-tabs--content" vs-label="Mis inversiones">
                      <GetInversion></GetInversion>
                      <vs-tabs vs-position="right">
                        <vs-tab vs-label="Mes 1">
                          <div>
                          </div>
                        </vs-tab>
                        <vs-tab vs-label="Mes 2">
                          <div>
                          </div>
                        </vs-tab>
                        <vs-tab vs-label="Mes 3">
                          <div>
                          </div>
                        </vs-tab>
                      </vs-tabs>
                    </vs-tab>
                    <vs-tab class="vs-tabs--content" vs-label="Contratos">
                      <div>
                        <Reinvert></Reinvert>
                      </div>
                    </vs-tab>
                    <vs-tab vs-label="Transferir">
                      <div>
                        <Transfer></Transfer>
                      </div>
                    </vs-tab>
                  </vs-tabs>
                </div>
              </vs-tab>
              <vs-tab vs-label="NOTICIAS">
                <div>
                </div>
              </vs-tab>
              <vs-tab vs-label="ESTRUCTURA">
                <div>
                </div>
              </vs-tab>
              <vs-tab vs-label="LIDERES">
                <div>
                </div>
              </vs-tab>
              <vs-tab vs-label="PERFIL">
                <div>
                  <vs-tabs vs-alignment="fixed">
                    <vs-tab class="vs-tabs--content" vs-label="Mi Perfil">
                      <div>
                        <Perfil></Perfil>
                      </div>
                    </vs-tab>
                    <vs-tab class="vs-tabs--content"  vs-label="Datos Sensibles">
                      <UdateSecurityDate></UdateSecurityDate>
                    </vs-tab>
                    <vs-tab class="vs-tabs--content"  vs-label="Actualizar Contraseña">
                      <div>
                        <UpdatePassword></UpdatePassword>
                      </div>
                    </vs-tab>
                  </vs-tabs>
                </div>

              </vs-tab>

            </vs-tabs>
```

Como se puede observar, ese es mi layout y todo lo cargo por componentes, que renderizan las tabs al momento de hacer clic.

```
  <vs-sidebar :reduce-not-hover-expand="notExpand" parent="body" default-index="1"
                color="success" class="sidebarx backImageMenu" spacer v-model="active">
      <div class="header-sidebar" slot="header">
        <div style="border: #CA0733 solid; border-radius: 100%">
          <div style="border-radius: 50%">
            <vs-avatar size="70px" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/85.jpg"/>
            <!--<vs-avatar size="70px" :src="user_perfil.urlAvatar"/>-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="">Bienvenido (a)</p>
          <h1>{{user_perfil.nombre}} {{user_perfil.apellido}}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <vs-sidebar-group class="backImageMenu" open title="Menú">
        <vs-sidebar-item style="background: #e3e3e3" index="5">
          <p>Capital base : <span style="font-weight: bold">700 BTC</span></p>
        </vs-sidebar-item>
        <vs-sidebar-group title="Transacciones">
          <vs-sidebar-item href="#Transferir" index="2.1">
            Historial
          </vs-sidebar-item>
          <vs-sidebar-item index="2.2">
            Mis comisiones
          </vs-sidebar-item>
          <vs-sidebar-item index="2.3">
            Lista de retiros
          </vs-sidebar-item>
          <vs-sidebar-item index="2.4">
            Depósitos
          </vs-sidebar-item>
          <vs-sidebar-item index="2.5">
            Transferir
          </vs-sidebar-item>
          <vs-sidebar-item index="2.6">
            Comprar BTC
          </vs-sidebar-item>
          <vs-sidebar-item index="2.7">
            Comprar paquetes
          </vs-sidebar-item>
        </vs-sidebar-group>
        <vs-sidebar-group icon="https" title="Seguridad">
          <vs-sidebar-item index="3.1">
            Cambiar contraseña
          </vs-sidebar-item>
          <vs-sidebar-item index="3.2">
            Segundo factor
          </vs-sidebar-item>
          <vs-sidebar-item index="3.3">
            Verificar cuenta
          </vs-sidebar-item>
        </vs-sidebar-group>
        <vs-sidebar-group title="Lenguaje">
          <vs-sidebar-item index="4.1">
            Español
          </vs-sidebar-item>
          <vs-sidebar-item index="4.2">
            Inglés
          </vs-sidebar-item>
        </vs-sidebar-group>
        <vs-sidebar-item index="3">
          Ayuda
        </vs-sidebar-item>
      </vs-sidebar-group>
      <div class="footer-sidebar" slot="footer">
        <el-row :gutter="200">
          <el-col :span="10">
            <vs-button icon="logout" type="border"></vs-button>
          </el-col>
          <el-col :span="14">
            <vs-button icon="settings" type="border"></vs-button>
          </el-col>
        </el-row>
      </div>
    </vs-sidebar>
```

luego tengo ese código que será mi menú.
Debo crear la navegación a las pestañas desde ese menú.

Gracias por las respuestas posibles.

El v-model está declarada como tab: '',

```
      tabClicked () {
    console.log('id tab actual', this.tabs)
    this.tabs = 4
    console.log('cambiar id de tab', this.tabs);
  },
```

[image: Console log]

ahora, viendo desde el componente de vue para chrome

[image: Vue component chrome]

Comment: Sí, al hacer el console, me manda el id de la tab en la cual estuve parado anteriormente, pero las tabs no se renderizan por href. Por ende, no tengo ni la más mínima idea de cómo llegar hasta cada tab desde cualquier otra acción.

Comment: La variable asociada al vmodel, simplemente toma los valores del id del tab. si la cambio por otra, pues sucede lo mismo.

Comment: No, simplemente provoca el cambio del valor mas no un cambio de tab. (Perdón por lo anterior, no había comprendido bien xd)

Comment: Ok vamos limpiando. Cambiar el v-model deberia cambiar el tab. Podrias poner en la pregunta como esta definida la variable del v-model y como se ve por consola? Es un objeto o solamente un numero?

Comment: Solo muestra un número, el objeto de la tab, lo muestra al inspeccionar con el componente de chrome como dejo en la foto

Comment: Exuste la tab al cual la estas cambiando no? Si no. Mañana puedo probar que pasa con ese componente. Pero es raro q no cambie. Y si no, es una pregunta para los q hicieron el componente

Comment: Sí, de echo hay 6 tabs como muestra la imagen, donde children tiene un objeto de 6, esas son las tabs que hay. Hice la pregunta a quienes crearon el componente hace ya 10 días. Sin respuesta. Muchas gracias por tus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo no se como estas declarando cada cosa, pero con el siguiente ejemplo podes ver que cambiando la variable data, que esta conectada al v-model del componente, en efecto cambia de tab.

```
<template>
    <div class="" >
    <vs-tabs v-model="Tabactivo">
      <vs-tab vs-label="Home">
        <div class="con-tab-ejemplo">
          Home
        </div>
      </vs-tab>
      <vs-tab vs-label="Service">
        <div class="con-tab-ejemplo">
          Service
        </div>
      </vs-tab>
    </vs-tabs>
    <vs-button @click="Tabactivo = 1">
        Siempre va a service
    </vs-button>
    <vs-button @click="cambiartab()">
        Este boton va por un metodo
    </vs-button>
    {{Tabactivo}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            Tabactivo: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        cambiartab() {
            this.Tabactivo = 1
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Si estas parado en el tab Home, y apretas el boton, automaticamente va al tab Service.

Sin ver como definiste las cosas, es dificil saber que pasa, pero este ejemplo que te acabo de pasar funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó. El error que tenía, era que estaba cambiando el valor del tab luego de dar click, o sea, en un método. Al parecer, debe cambiarse el valor inmediatamente se hace click. Con tu ejemplo, realmente cambia de pestaña.

Comment: @EdwinRendoonCadavid pero en un metodo deberia andar exactamente igual.. ahora lo pruebo

Comment: @EdwinRendoonCadavid no se como escribiste tu metodo, pero ahora te edito la respuesta. Es exactamente igual.

Comment: Gracias, literalmente no sé qué sucedía. Funciona sí. Intenté reiniciar la App para que compilara de nuevo y sí funciona con el método. Después de darle mil vueltas, la solución era super sencilla. Creo que ya estaba algo liado con ello. Gracias nuevamente.